# parallel code slower on multicore AMD

Tags: gcc, intel, amd-processor

parallelized code(openmp), compiled on and intel (linux) with gcc, runs much faster on an intel computer than on an AMD with twice as many cores. I see that all the cores are in use but it takes about 10 times more cpu time on the AMD. I had heard about "cripple AMD" in intel compiler, but I am using gcc! Thanks in advance

Comment: what are exact names of used AMD and Intel CPUs?

Comment: AMD opteron 6234 and intel Xeon(E5520).

Answer (score 0):

Intel has hyper-threading technology in their modern processor cores which essentially means that you have multiple hardware contexts running on a single core simultaneously, r you taking this into account, when you make the comparison ??

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.